# Make a div stretch left to infinity

Tags: css, infinity

I am looking to have `<h2>` tags stretch the background to the left of the browser window but don't seem to be able to.  Can anyone help?

Jsfiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/4fm8x/20](http://jsfiddle.net/4fm8x/20)

The wrapper div is needed for centring the page on larger resolution screens.  I would like to keep this centred if possible.

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: remove  "margin: 20px auto;" from #wrapper

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4fm8x/20/ is the jsfiddle.  I can't remove the auto left/right margin as the container/wrapper is to center the content at larger resolutions.

Comment: Just an observation: `position` can be `absolute, relative, fixed or static`. Remove this line `position: inline;` from your `#wrapper` div :)

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, I had already removed this in my working version.  This is what happens when you code late at night.  ty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as your div is inside a smaller parent, it will be hard to stretch it to browser-borders. what should work is using the full space and then center each item (except h2). You would need an extra span inside the h2 to hold the actual content.

The minified version:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h2><span>This is a header/title</span></h2>
    <p>This is the text.</p>
</div>
```

and

```
p {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h2 {
    width:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FF8C00;
}

h2 span {
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

or in your style: http://jsfiddle.net/YW2ce/

Comment: This was what i was worried about.  So I will have to create a new class which will assign a width of all content and set an auto margin left and right on it.  Oh well, thank you for your assistance.